# Blue mouse over effect on button in Blend / WPF

Tags: wpf, button, blend

I just started getting used to WPF using Blend for Visual Studio. I created previous programs with the standart Windows Forms and now want to get to something more modern.
But I already encountered a main problem after like 5 Minutes.
I added a button with an background image with a transperancy. That worked like a charm, but the problem is that, when I run the application, the button always gets blue when the Mouse hovers it. I do not want this blue effect but can't find the option to disable it in Blend. 
Hope someone can help me with this stupid question, Windows Forms was a little

Comment: Please post a screenshot that illustrates this blue effect you're describing.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2uw0n0auavw51u1/Screenshot%202014-11-10%2019.54.58.png?dl=0 this happens

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're describing is the default state behavior for the button.  You would have to create a custom template or style to change it.  Example:

```
<Button Content="Button">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

I am demonstrating two properties changes here: `Background` & `Foreground`.  You may have as many as you want and change them to whatever value you wish.  If you don't want any changes, simply remove `Style.Triggers` or a particular property within it.

Here's a demo for you, since you're new:

[image]

Here's the `Resource Dictionary` way:

[image]

Create a `Resource Dictionary` and add a style to it:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Place this in your `App.xaml` or wherever you merge your resource dictionaries:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ButtonStyles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then simply specify the style for your button:

```
Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Sorry, I am a completly new to Blend, so where do I need to add this code?

Comment: @BfN_Turin There are many locations where you can add this: `Resource Dictionary`, at the top of the window as a `Static Resource` or simply as the local style in the button itself, as I demonstrated above: `<Button ...> That style </Button>`

Comment: So if I want to do it for all buttons a Resource Dictionary would be the best, right?

Comment: @BfN_Turin Absolutely.  Check out the video above for the local style.  I'll add another one for `Resource Dictionary` in a minute.

Comment: @BfN_Turin I added the guide to show how to do it via `Resource Dictionary`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am honestly feeling total lost right now, the interface of Blend is just so totally confusing compared to the normal visual studio i used before... So I clicked on Ressources on the top right. I added a new one, gave it a name and double clicked it. I got into a code window of the ResourceDictonary. Problem is i get an error when adding your code there... Ah sorry, just saw the second one, look easier! :) I'll give it a try and check if it works

Comment: @BfN_Turin Yeah, the second one is for Visual Studio, but it should be similar in Blend.  Let me know if you're having issues and I'll do a Blend one.

Comment: Hi, very big thanks! I could somehow skip the last step, do not really know why, but it worked without it.

Comment: Ah ok, but it does work, so it does not matter. :) Marked it as correct, very big thanks!

Comment: @BfN_Turin No problem.  Basically, without a key, the style will be applied to every button in the application.  If you specify a key, then you can add that style to specific buttons, rather than all of them.